# Превышен лимит исполнения программы

Tags: python

Написал программу для такой задачи: есть скобочная последовательность из скобок разных типов, количество типов не ограничено. Открывающая скобка i-го типа обозначается как [(i, закрывающая – как ])i, типы нумеруются с 1. Нужно проверять инпут на правильную последовательность скобок. Но это не так важно. Почему-то после ввода последовательности программа не запускается и бесконечно грузится. Что тут может быть не так?

```
    s = input()
    stack = []
    c = 0
    while c < len(s)-1:
       tally = 0
       if s[c] == '[':
           c+=1
    while c != len(s) and s[c] == '(':
       tally, c = tally+1, c+1
       stack.append(tally)
       if s[c] == ']':
         c+=1
       elif len(stack) == 0:
         stack.append('d')
         break
    while c != len(s) and s[c] == ')':
       tally, c = tally+1, c+1
       if tally != stack[-1]:
          break
          stack.pop()
       else:
          break
  
    if len(stack) == 0:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: Раз требует ввести последовательность, то разумеется запускается. Поставь там сям print то сё и смотри, что происходит. Если ты ничего не выводишь в процессе отладки, то ничего и не узнаешь.

Comment: "Не так" тут то, что вы даже не удосужились запустить ваш код в отладчике. Ну, или как вам тут уже посоветовали, не понаставляли print(). Т.е. писать программы -  ОК, а отлаживать - черная и неблагодарная работа, пусть кто-то за меня подумает?  Подсказка: первый же цикл, который вы написали -  как вы из него собираетесь выходить даже в случае вот такой элементарной входной строки [()] ? Помните, 80% времени работы программиста - это отладка, и только 20, а то и еще меньше - написание кода. Где ошибка -  я вам указал, а вот дальше -  учитесь отлаживать, пригодиться.